# Strtok removes first character in token C

Tags: c, string, pointers, tokenize, strtok

I have this little problem when trying to tokenize a string from a http request directed at my "home made" Http server.

Basicly I am using these lines of code to tokneize.

```
    token = strtok(bufptr, "\n");

    while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s \n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
```

The problem is that for every token, the first character is removed from the tokenized string. How can I solve this?

I have tried copying the string, I have tried using strstr, but I have not yet succeded. I bet there is something pretty easy I am doing wrong.

Best regards.

Comment: What's the content of *bufptr*?

Comment: It is a http get request from the browser.

Comment: Ok, but the exact content, can you print it out to the console with printf ?

Comment: Yes. I will post here in a while. Going home from uni now.

Comment: @ThomasHolden I think that you need to use \r\n and not \n only. Have you considered it?

Comment: I will try when I get home, and report back.

Comment: This is the content of prtbuf.

GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like p4|

Comment: Alessando: Thanks, it worked when I tried with \r\n. I think its wired though, because I read the UNIX does not use that delimiter for newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `'\r'` in the string.  (@Alessandro Suglia)

```
 printf("%sx\n", "abc\r");  // x substituted for space
```

Prints:

```
 xbc
```

The `'\r'` (return) move the print position to the beginning of the line.  Then `'x'` overwrites `'a'`.  This appears as the OP observed "the first character is removed from the tokenized string".

Answer (score 0):

This is working just fine:

```
char bufptr[] = "aaaa\nbbbb\ncccc\nddd";
char *token;
token = strtok(bufptr, "\n");

while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s \n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```

output is:

```
aaaa 
bbbb 
cccc 
ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the \r\n as delimiter instead of only \n
I did not think UNIX sent \r\n for newline, but seems that it does? Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is having this problem. The HTTP protocol uses the \r\n delimiters after the header lines, and a CRLN for seperating the body from the header. CRLN is \r\n\r\n as I understood it.

From my searching around the web I did not find alot easy readable information about the protocol. Of course, you do have the RFCs.

Thanks for the help everybody. Btw, I could never figure out how to accept an answer.